# Wicket and Leaflet multipolygon

Tags: javascript, jquery, wicket, gis, leaflet

I'm trying to make a multipolygon object using the Wicket plugin.  I started using the plugin, but now I'm sort of drifting away. If I can figure out just how to use it, it would help me a ton.

I'm also new to leaflet and don't really understand what the documentation says for multipolygon.  I am able to make regular polygons but no multipolygon.

Has anybody worked with these libraries before?

Here's my attempt:

```
map = new L.Map("map");
wkt = new Wkt.Wkt();
val = $("#wktInput").val();
output = wkt.read( val );

var temp = new Array();
for( i=0; i<output[0][0].length; i++ )
    temp[i] = new L.LatLng(output[0][0][i].x, output[0][0][i].y);

L.polygon( temp ).addTo( map ); //This works
L.multiPolygon( temp ).addTo( map ); //This doesn't
```

So I figured, for multipolygon, I need another array that contains temp, so I tried that also but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how it works, but I've found a useful library that pertains to what you are talking about. "Leaflet-paste" is an open source project on GitHub that allows you to paste WKT into a Leaflet-JS map using the Wicket Library.

Here's a link to the repository: https://github.com/tnightingale/Leaflet.paste

And a demo can be found here: http://tnightingale.github.com/Leaflet.paste/demo.html